# How to search a MongoDB database filtered by a specific value

Tags: php, regex, search, mongodb, find

I am trying to search a MongoDB database filtering on a specific data item. Specifically, I want USA = PG-13 for my filter.

**How to make a request: to get movies, where MPAA for USA = PG-13?**

collection **country:**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d05000080"),
   "en": "USA" 
}
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d0500007f"),
   "en": "Hong Kong" 
}
```

collection **movie:**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d05000081"),
   "movieId": {
     "imdb": "0848228" 
  },
   "movieTitle": "The Avengers",
   "movieYearSpan": {
     "start": "2012",
     "end": "2012" 
  },
   "movieType": "Movie",
   "movieMpaa": {
     "verdict": "Rated PG-13",
     "0": {
       "mpaa": "IIA",
       "country": ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d0500007f") 
    },
     "1": {
       "mpaa": "PG-13",
       "country": ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d05000080") 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I tried to first get the ID for the USA.

```
$cursorCountry = $collectionCountry->find(array("en" => "USA"));
$idCountry = $cursorCountry->getNext();
$_id = $idCountry["_id"];
$cursorMovie = $collectionMovie->find(array("movieMpaa.country" => $_id, "movieMpaa.mpaa" => "PG-13"));
```

Does not work!
How then to make a request?
To get movies, where MPAA for USA = PG-13?

Comment: Does `$_id = new MongoId($_id)` help? Regardless, I would change the database as @Gates VP's suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is laid out, there is no good query here.

If you can change your `movies` collection to the following, then your query will work:

```
   "movieMpaa": {
     "verdict": "Rated PG-13",
     "countries": [
         {
           "mpaa": "IIA",
           "country": ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d0500007f") 
       },
         {
           "mpaa": "PG-13",
           "country": ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d05000080") 
        } 
     ]
```

When `movieMpaa.countries` is an array of objects, then you can query into that array for `movieMpaa.countries.country`. MongoDB will recognize the array and "drill into" the objects.

However, there is another way structure this that probably much easier longer term:

```
   "movieMpaa": {
     "verdict": "Rated PG-13",
     "countries": {
         ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d0500007f") : { "mpaa": "IIA" },
         ObjectId("4fd79ec34c9fda9d05000080") : { "mpaa": "PG-13" }
     }
```

If a country can only have one rating, then technically that `countries` value is a dictionary of `Countries => ratings`. The structure above stores them this way.

However, the use of `ObjectId` is a little ugly there. Note that you can override the ID in the `country` collection. Consider using the 2 or 3-character ISO codes instead. These are easier to read.

```
   "movieMpaa": {
     "verdict": "Rated PG-13",
     "countries": {
         "UK" : { "mpaa": "IIA" },
         "US" : { "mpaa": "PG-13" }
     }

db.movies.find({'movieMpaa.countries.US': 'PG-13'})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
In this way, I will design.
If we project this way the database, will not be able to get all movies rated PG-13.
Tell me how to do case-insensitive search?

Comment: Use the regex features. From the shell you can do `db.movies.find({'movieMpaa.countries.US': /PG-13/i })`. You will need to read the docs for the same version in PHP. It involves the `MongoRegex` object.